# What do you mean by frequency of SHM and how is it related to angle covered in a UCM?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

What is the difference between angular velocity and angular frequency and in what reference is it used in SHM?

Comment: Angular frequency = $2\pi$ / angular velocity

Comment: Angular velocity generally refers to something which is rotating or moving in a circle.  It can be expressed with any unit if angle over time.
The angular frequency can be found for any variable described by a sinusoidal function of time.  It is normally expressed in radians/sec = 2π (cycles/sec).